# inserting multiple rows into SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert lots of rows into a 2 column table at once where one of the values remains constant. This is what I have tried: -

```
insert into testtable (value1,value2) 
    select 
      123,
      ( SELECT [title] FROM [dbo].[images])
```

This gives me the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I could insert each row one at a time but I was wondering if there is a way I g=could do the whole lot in one go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error, do not put two `SELECT` in there :

```
INSERT INTO testtable (value1,value2) 
SELECT 123, [title] 
FROM [dbo].[images];
```